# Fade out div as it's dragged near another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a draggable div that can be dropped into a droppable div. This works fine. The draggable div contains a `span` element. I would like this `span` element to fade out as it approaches the droppable div.

I have a draggable fadeout/in example based on another answer, which applies to when you drag the element to the side of the window. I tried modifying this to fit my needs but it doesn't sem to be working for some reason.

---

Drag the red sqaure to the right handside. you will notice it fades in/out as you drag it.

**Demo Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EybmN/32/**

```
$('#draggable').draggable({
  drag: function(event, ui) {
  console.log(ui.helper.find('span'));
    ui.helper.find('span').css('opacity', 1 - ui.position.left / $(window).width());
  }
});
```

---

My attempt of modifying this to have the behaviour explained above.

**Demo http://jsfiddle.net/EybmN/30/**

```
$('#draggable').draggable({
  drag: function(event, ui) {
  console.log(ui.helper.find('span'));
    $el = $('.droppable.blue');
    var bottom = $el.position().top + $el.outerHeight(true);
    var $span = ui.helper.find('span');
   $span.css('opacity', 1 - $span.top / bottom);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the `ui` position. Then you need to calculate that with the distance from the div.

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EybmN/34/

```
$('#draggable').draggable({
  connectToDroppable: '.droppable',
  revert: 'invalid',
  drag: function(event, ui) {
    var $span = ui.helper.find('span');
    var opacity = ((ui.helper.offset().top - ui.helper.outerHeight()) - ($('.droppable.blue').offset().top + $('.droppable.blue').outerHeight())) / 100;
    $span.css('opacity', opacity);
  }
});
$(".droppable").droppable({
  accept: '#draggable',
  drop: function(event, ui) {

  }
});
```

Edit

If you would like it more gradual, then get the start position and then calculate the percentage based on the dragging position.

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EybmN/35/

```
var startPos = 0;
$('#draggable').draggable({
  connectToDroppable: '.droppable',
  revert: 'invalid',
  drag: function(event, ui) {
  if(!startPos) startPos = ui.helper.offset().top;
    var $span = ui.helper.find('span');
    var opacity = (ui.helper.offset().top - (ui.helper.outerHeight()*2.5) - ($('.droppable.blue').offset().top + $('.droppable.blue').outerHeight())) / startPos + .5;
    $span.css('opacity', opacity);
  }
});
$(".droppable").droppable({
  accept: '#draggable',
  drop: function(event, ui) {

  }
});
```

Comment: wow! thanks! I was beginning to think this wasn't possible. Is there any way of making the fade more gradual? Thanks again.

Comment: Edited my answer for a more gradual fade